# How to open short cut word file on a USB drive?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

**I was working on an article and my work didn't get saved between changes.**

My auto save was on, backup to Onedrive wasn't on, and I remember hurrying up closing the document and seeing "Save as a copy" option instead of the usual "Save"  or"Save as". I just closed the document knowing it was already saved on my desktop. I last saved at at 11:09pm (I'm 95% sure this is the version I want) But when I opened it again, the version I was seeing was from 5:20pm.

Anyways, after trying to browse through AutoSave location,recently opened etc nothing came of it, in fear of over writing the file I quickly installed EaseUS Data Recovery. **It found a shortcut word file saved at 11:09pm which I recovered to my external USB drive (D:)**

**EDIT: I also tried to recover my file again right now using the Ease Us recovery ..but this time through the USB drive instead of the C drive, and i got this version saved at 7pm which i have saved on my desktop. ( i haven't tried anything with this version yet)**

Now I have been trying to get it in its original form since last night. I have already missed my deadline so I'm already super late.

But this is what I have done so far:

**almost every website recommended the same line of words to type in cmd; Ran not as an administrator= 
https://www.anysoftwaretools.com/fix-files-folders-become-shortcuts/**

**My last saved was old with barely any words on it , so this didn't help me= https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/887-word-auto-recover-file-location.html**

**How to recover shortcut files on a USB= 
https://youtu.be/sz377SjQP_c**

**Didn't understand how to edit path here so did't help me =https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/**

**Ran CMD as an administrator after reading this and added a pathway without the colon as another website said it was only required for older versions of windows=
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command**

Other stuff I looked at but didn't think applied to me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032646/ls-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-b?rq=1

https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12550-how-to-fix-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error

I have tried scanning my computer for viruses & updates, changed my username to something with no special characters in it because I learnt Windows OS didn't like that, tried using cmd: adding my username, then trying it without username, putting in "C:"as recovery location (after i copied the shortcut to desktop).

I'm at a total loss.I CANNOT rewrite the article the way I wrote it before, is there still hope for me?

**NOTE: REMEMBER, I have the shortcut word version on USB, and now (after trying it just a few min ago) another saved version on Desktop...and  I'm just trying to get it to open**

**and im mostly a lurker, but first time poster so new on this forum, so might not know how to reply+formatting**

Comment: if its a Word search on the computer for, if the läßt opening of the file will not Show your changes them im think im sorry for you

Comment: Download [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/), start it and let it index the disk, then search for all occurrences of the file-name on the disk.